# Samsung Galaxy Tab A7 Lite does not boot after Odin flash (stock rom)

Tags: samsung

I have tried different firmware (original and updated - two each) different usb cables and different usb ports.
I have factory reset and cleared cache numerous times, but every time the tablet only boots to the screen "Samsung Galaxy Powered by Android" and goes no further. I can boot to Recovery, Fastboot mode and Download, but not to System. The firmware is correct - downloaded with Frija.
Please , Can anyone help

Comment: How long did you wait for first boot?

Comment: I left it for about one hour.

Comment: It would probably help others that try to answer your question, if you'd added the model to your question.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/4480193